# how to dynamically add row to table in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am trying to achieve the functionality where I can add/update/delete rows dynamically to any table using EF core. Table name is available as string.

I have tried few ways but nothing seems working...

Approach 1:

```
 string tablename = "someTableName";
    SomeDbContext context = new SomeDbContext();
    var type = context.Model.FindEntityType(tablename);
   
    if (type != null)
    {
        var query = context.Set(type);
        query.Add(new {
                 Id = 1,
                 someId1 = 64089,
                 someId2 = 64087,
                 comment= "some random testing" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Error message:

```
The type arguments for method 'method' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Approach 2:

```
        Type t = Type.GetType(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + tablename);
        var dbset = context.Set(t);
```

Error message: same as above.

Approach 3:

```
var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + tablename;
var entitytype = Type.GetType(name);
var results = context
    .GetType()
    .GetMethod("Set")
    .MakeGenericMethod(entitytype)
    .Invoke(context, null);
```

Error message:

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: 'Ambiguous match found.'
```

Can anyone help me with pointing to right direction.

I am able to resolve the entity type in all 3 approaches but failed when it comes to calling Set method on Context.

Comment: EF deals with *objects*, not tables and rows. If you want to store a new Customer object to the database, create it and call `context.Add(newCustomer);`. This will start tracking the new object in the `Added` state. When the time comes to commit the changes, call `SaveChanges` to store *all* pending changes, including all DELETEs, UPDATEs, INSERTs

Comment: There's no need for reflection code at all.

Comment: This may look great in theory, but how is it practically feasible? Can any table simply accept an empty row? Doesn't each table require custom validation and can any table be inserted in isolation? Not likely.

Comment: This is bad in theory, even if some product idiosyncrasies (like semi-hidden ROWIDs) make it feasible (not practical). In SQL, the language, there's no way to identify individual rows beyond their values. If 10 rows have identical values there's no way to update or delete a *specific* row. Even in DBs with ROWIDs, those aren't part of any index so searching by them can be very slow.

Comment: Validation will be done separately. Empty row is just for demo purpose. Table will contains lots of columns with Id columnas primary key.

Comment: This sounds like XY problem. In order to add something, in addition for "table name" you must have some object containing the data. So where you are getting from that "table name" and data object? What is the actual type of that data object? etc. Because if you have correctly instantiated object (entity instance), `DbContext` has methods `Add(object x)`, `Update(object x)`, `Remove(object x)` etc. which use `x.GetType()` to determine the correct set. And even if you somehow get access to `DbSet` via reflection, you still have to pass correct object type. So you don't need "table name" ...

Comment: *Validation will be done separately. Empty row is just for demo purpose.* -- That's what I suspected and that demonstrates that there's no point in using this untyped method. It means you're always creating an object of some type after which the object can simply be added by `context.Add`.

Comment: ... at all, just the entity instances of the proper entity type. Same for update and delete. @Gert Indeed.

Comment: @Ivan I am getting table name and object data from UI as json formatted.
I am trying to write general webapi for data manipulation.

Comment: @GertArnold You are right... I just deserialize data to correct type and then Add, update and delete are working fine.

Comment: So, what you get from WebAPI `tablename` or `ClassName`? Json contains table columns or property names?

Comment: I get class name of EF model and a separate json object containing all  properties.

Comment: The full power of EF is shown during compile-time. But you are doing something at runtime. In this case, EF is not your assistant, just give it up.

Comment: Will prepare solution tomorrow. Nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented simple extension methods which accepts `className` and `json` string and then uses reflection to invoke the appropriate method. Used Newtonsoft.Json for deserialization.

Usage sample:

```cs
var className = "someTableName";
var json = "{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"someName\" }";
context.AddEntity(className, json);
// or other methods
context.UpdateEntity(className, json);
context.RemoveEntity(className, json);
```

And extension implementation:

```cs
public static class DynamicChangeTrackerExtensions
{
    public static void AddEntity(this DbContext context, string className, string jsonData)
    {
        var entityType = GetEntityType(context, className);

        _addMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType).Invoke(null, new object?[] { context, jsonData });
    }

    public static void RemoveEntity(this DbContext context, string className, string jsonData)
    {
        var entityType = GetEntityType(context, className);

        _removeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType).Invoke(null, new object?[] { context, jsonData });
    }

    public static void UpdateEntity(this DbContext context, string className, string jsonData)
    {
        var entityType = GetEntityType(context, className);

        _updateMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType).Invoke(null, new object?[] { context, jsonData });
    }

    static IEntityType GetEntityType(DbContext context, string className)
    {
        var entityType = context.Model
            .GetEntityTypes()
            .SingleOrDefault(et => et.ClrType.Name == className);

        return entityType ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"No class found for '{className}'");
    }

    static MethodInfo _addMethod = typeof(DynamicChangeTrackerExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(AddInternal), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)!;
    static MethodInfo _removeMethod = typeof(DynamicChangeTrackerExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(RemoveInternal), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)!;
    static MethodInfo _updateMethod = typeof(DynamicChangeTrackerExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(UpdateInternal), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)!;

    static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonData)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    static void AddInternal<T>(this DbContext context, string jsonData) 
        where T : class
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(Deserialize<T>(jsonData));
    }

    static void RemoveInternal<T>(this DbContext context, string jsonData) 
        where T : class
    {
        context.Set<T>().Remove(Deserialize<T>(jsonData));
    }

    static void UpdateInternal<T>(this DbContext context, string jsonData) 
        where T : class
    {
        context.Set<T>().Update(Deserialize<T>(jsonData));
    }
}
```